# TinyCSS and GTK Theme @define-color

Tags: python, css, colors, gtk

I'm developing an application to parse GTK+3 themes. This application uses TinyCSS library.

It look like TinyCSS is just ignoring lines like

```
@define-color base_color #FAFAFA;
```

This definitions are in parser.styleSheets[0].errors.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@define-color` isn't a valid at-rule in standard CSS syntax. You'll have to patch TinyCSS to understand it, or else use a different parser that understands GTK's modifications to CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I'm developing my own parser using Pyparsing. Any better suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is to modify an existing CSS parser. Never write it yourself when you can adapt it.